# how to sort dictionary inside list and manipulate data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, inventory-management

I am working on something like inventory management, I am stuck in sorting and adding duplicae item by some condiiton. My code is down below and its working fine up to the data is in list  "print(c.data_dict)"

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

class Supplier:
    def __init__(self, name, address, email, contact_no):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.email = email
        self.contact_no = contact_no

class Product:
   def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Company(Supplier, Product):
    data_dict = []
    def purchase(self, supplier_obj, product_obj, qty, date):
    self.data_dict.append({'supplier': supplier_obj.name, 'product': product_obj.name, 'qty': qty, 'date': date})
    return self.data_dict

s1 = Supplier('Amazon', 'kalawad road', 'amazon@gmail.com', '987686')
s2 = Supplier('Flipkart', 'university road', 'flipkart@gmail.com', '657457')
s3 = Supplier('Alibaba', 'china town road', 'alibaba@qq.com', '365213')

p1 = Product('Laptop')
p2 = Product('printer')
p3 = Product('computer')

c = Company(None, None, None, None)
c.purchase(s1, p1, 10, '2019-10-10')
c.purchase(s1, p1, 10, '2019-10-10')
c.purchase(s1, p2, 20, '2018-11-11')
c.purchase(s1, p2, 30, '2018-12-12')
c.purchase(s1, p3, 40, '2016-10-10')
c.purchase(s2, p3, 10, '2019-11-11')
c.purchase(s2, p3, 11, '2019-11-11')
c.purchase(s3, p1, 6, '2019-03-04')
c.purchase(s3, p3, 9, '2019-02-02')
print(c.data_dict)
```

i get list containing like

```
[{'supplier': 'Amazon', 'product': 'Laptop', 'qty': 10, 'date': '2019-10-10'}, 
 {'supplier': 'Amazon', 'product': 'Laptop', 'qty': 10, 'date': '2019-10- 10'}, 
{'supplier': 'Amazon', 'product': 'printer', 'qty': 20, 'date': '2018-11-11'},
 {'supplier': 'Amazon', 'product': 'printer', 'qty': 30, 'date': '2018-12-12'},
 {'supplier': 'Amazon', 'product': 'computer', 'qty': 40, 'date':'2016-10-10'},
 {'supplier': 'Flipkart', 'product': 'computer', 'qty': 10,'date': '2019-11-11'},
 {'supplier': 'Flipkart', 'product': 'computer', 'qty': 11, 'date': '2019-11-11'},     
{'supplier': 'Alibaba', 'product': 'Laptop', 'qty': 6, 'date': '2019-03-04'}, 
{'supplier': 'Alibaba', 'product':'computer', 'qty': 9, 'date': '2019-02-02'}]
```

where Amazon, FLipkart & allibaba is Supplier Name,  Laptop-Printer-Computer is product name and qty is quantity and date is also there.

I am trying to do sort above list in a way that if same date from same supplier is there, qty should be added. eg. in Amazon-- qty of printer should be 50 , as show in output.   How can i do it? 
i have tried with itertool and operator module to get it done, but not getting proper output.

My expexcted output is

```
sample output

 Amazon
 01-01-2019      laptop       10
 02-02-1019      laptop       10
 03-03-2019      printer      50
 03-03-2019      computer     40

 Flipkart
 01-01-2019      computer      10
 31-01-2019      computer      11

 Alibaba
 2019-03-04      laptop        6
 2019-02-02      computer      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter to do the heavy lifting.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for d in c.data_dict:
        counter[d['supplier'],d['product'],d['date']] += d['qty']
```

That gives totals per supplier, product and date:

```
>>> counter
Counter({('Amazon', 'computer', '2016-10-10'): 40, ('Amazon', 'printer', '2018-12-12'): 30, ('Flipkart', 'computer', '2019-11-11'): 21, ('Amazon', 'printer', '2018-11-11'): 20, ('Amazon', 'Laptop', '2019-10-10'): 10, ('Amazon', 'Laptop', '2019-10- 10'): 10, ('Alibaba', 'computer', '2019-02-02'): 9, ('Alibaba', 'Laptop', '2019-03-04'): 6})
```

To print it out *sorted* by supplier, product and date, you can do this. Your sample output doesn't agree with the dates in the sample input in the question, so the results are not the same.

```
>>> for (supplier, product, date), qty in sorted(counter.items()):
        print(supplier, product, date, qty)

('Alibaba', 'Laptop', '2019-03-04', 6)
('Alibaba', 'computer', '2019-02-02', 9)
('Amazon', 'Laptop', '2019-10- 10', 10)
('Amazon', 'Laptop', '2019-10-10', 10)
('Amazon', 'computer', '2016-10-10', 40)
('Amazon', 'printer', '2018-11-11', 20)
('Amazon', 'printer', '2018-12-12', 30)
('Flipkart', 'computer', '2019-11-11', 21)
```

Add a call to `format()` in the `print()` call to make it pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you aren't really trying to sort, you are trying to transform the data

If I understand correctly when a company purchases a product that they have already purchased from the same supplier on the same day we should add the quantity.

One simple way to do this is add this logic to the purchase function

```
def purchase(self, supplier_obj, product_obj, qty, date):
    for purchase in self.data_dict:
        if purchase['supplier'] == supplier_obj.name and purchase['product'] == product_obj.name and purchase['date'] == date:
            purchase['qty']+=qty
            return self.data_dict
    self.data_dict.append({'supplier': supplier_obj.name, 'product': product_obj.name, 'qty': qty, 'date': date})
    return self.data_dict
```

A more efficient way to do it would be to store the data in a large dictionary and only on calling print do you format it to the way you want. The code above though should format your list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can remove duplicates and sum together the  same products that were added same day and by same company.

```
new_data = []
for entry in data:
    if entry not in new_data:
        for i in new_data:
            if all([entry['product'] == i['product'],
                    entry['supplier'] == i['supplier'],
                    entry['date'] == i['date']]):
                i['qty'] += entry['qty']
                break
        new_data.append(entry)

print(*new_data, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
{'date': '2019-10-10', 'product': 'Laptop', 'supplier': 'Amazon', 'qty': 10}
{'date': '2018-11-11', 'product': 'printer', 'supplier': 'Amazon', 'qty': 20}
{'date': '2018-12-12', 'product': 'printer', 'supplier': 'Amazon', 'qty': 30}
{'date': '2016-10-10', 'product': 'computer', 'supplier': 'Amazon', 'qty': 40}
{'date': '2019-11-11', 'product': 'computer', 'supplier': 'Flipkart', 'qty': 21}
{'date': '2019-11-11', 'product': 'computer', 'supplier': 'Flipkart', 'qty': 11}
{'date': '2019-03-04', 'product': 'Laptop', 'supplier': 'Alibaba', 'qty': 6}
{'date': '2019-02-02', 'product': 'computer', 'supplier': 'Alibaba', 'qty': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of fun playing around how the data would be easily modified.
It isn't the prettiest way, please refer to Filip answer if you want something effective without changing your code to much.

```
import datetime
import attr

Supplier= attr.make_class('Supplier',['name', 'address', 'email', 'contact_no', 'purchase_per_date_per_product'])

Product = attr.make_class('Product',['name'])

Purchase = attr.make_class('Purchase',['supplier', 'product','qty','date'])

class Company():
    data_dict = {}
    def add_purchase(self, supplier_obj, product_obj, qty, date):
        if [product_obj,date] in supplier_obj.purchase_per_date_per_product:
            self.data_dict[supplier_obj.name][date][product_obj.name]+= qty
        else:
            if supplier_obj.name not in self.data_dict:
                self.data_dict[supplier_obj.name]={}
            supplier_obj.purchase_per_date_per_product += [[product_obj,date]]
            self.data_dict[supplier_obj.name][date]={product_obj.name:qty}
        return self.data_dict
```